# How can I load nib from UIViews in iOS 4?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4

How can I load nib from a UIView in iOS 4 ?

I don't have a UIViewController, since I'm adding this custom view to a parent view.

I want to initialize this custom view from a nib file. Which initializer should I use ? initWithFrame or initWithCoder ?

So far, I've only assigned the custom class in the interface builder. (See pic: http://cl.ly/7pmj). Is this necessary ? If so, it is still not working, why is it not enough ?

**NB** I've found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648299/how-to-load-a-uiview-from-a-nib) in StackOverflow. However, it doesn't explain how to initialize the view itself with the nib.

I need to customize **drawRect** method, for this view, so I can't just add a subview from a nib file. I need the view itself being initialized from the nib file.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the method from the related question (NSBundle loadNibNamed) and make sure the owner in that call is an object that has an IBOutlet for the view in question.

Hook that iboutlet up to the view in interface builder (you will need to set the class of the owner in IB to the class of the owner in your load nib call).

The nib will load the view into that iboutlet variable.

In .h file:

```
IBOutlet UIView *myView;
```

in .m file:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"viewToLoad" owner:self options:nil];
[someOtherView addSubView:myView];
```

The rest is in IB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a must to change the custom view class in your nib file. 
Make sure two things:
1. Go to yourCustomView.nib file, select the view in object, then make sure the custom class is correct under the identity inspector. 
2. In the youCustomView.m file, make sure you have this part:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder 
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) 
    {
       //add custom change after init from nib. 
    }
    return self;
}
```